# Nav bar not lining up with psd

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, psd

I have a psd that is based on the 960 grid system which I am converting using bootstrap however there is padding to the left and right of the nav bar however I do not feel I am doing it right even though it looks ok

I am using bootstrap version 3.3.7

Image From Below Html
[image]

Image from Psd

[image]

Html for which produces the first image.

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="jumpbotron-inner text-center">
        <h1>We build well desgined websites</h1>
        <h4>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.</h4>
        <span>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
        Get Started
        </a>
        </span>
        <span>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
        Learn More
        </a>
        </span>
        <br />
        <img src="image/browser.png">
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Which produces the first image I seem to have to put margin-right and left of 200px to get it to line up

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 220px;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 64px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    border: none;
    margin-right: 220px;
}
```

Complete css for ref

```css
/*--------------begin header -------------*/

body > div.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top {
    background: transparent;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    border: none;
    margin-right: 220px;
}
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url(image/background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: none !important;
    padding-bottom: none !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    max-height: 490px;
}
body > div.jumbotron > div > h1 {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
body > div.jumbotron > div > h4 {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
body > div.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top > div.navbar-inner > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a {
    background-color: black;
    color: white !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: white !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
.navbar-brand {
    background-image: url (image/brand.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 220px;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 64px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    border: none;
    margin-right: 220px;
}
/*--------------end header -------------*/
/*--------------begin services  -------------*/

.info-plan,
.info-design,
.info-develop,
.info launch {
    background-image: url('/image/services-sprtie.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.info-plan {
    height: 100px;
    background-position: -5px -5px;
}
/*--------------begin reset -------------*/

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.alert {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.col-xs-1,
.col-sm-1,
.col-md-1,
.col-sm-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-sm-2,
.col-md-2,
.col-sm-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-sm-3,
.col-md-3,
.col-sm-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-sm-4,
.col-md-4,
.col-sm-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-md-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-sm-6,
.col-md-6,
.col-sm-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-sm-7,
.col-md-7,
.col-sm-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-sm-8,
.col-md-8,
.col-sm-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-sm-9,
.col-md-9,
.col-sm-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-sm-10,
.col-md-10,
.col-sm-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-sm-11,
.col-md-11,
.col-sm-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12,
.col-md-12,
.col-sm-12 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.row {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.footer {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border-top: none;
}
.panel {
    border: none;
}
/*--------------end reset -------------*/
```

**Edit 2**

I tried using

```
.custom-container {
  border:1px solid red;
  max-width:960px;
}
```

But its made the whole site 960px i just want the nav and the content area to confirm to that but leave the jumbotron to be of full width.

**Edit 3**

This is my attempt but as you will see from screen shot 3 it is not working

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="container custom-container">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

     <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
            <div class="navbar-inner">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

       </div>
        </div>

        </div>
```

Screen shot 3
[image]

Comment: The 220px is ment to be there as was not sure how to get it to align in first place but is it the right way of doing it.

Comment: so... you want the navbar to be narrower i.e pulled together tighter left and right?

Comment: @ProEvilz correct it should look like the second image that is from the psd.

Comment: @ProEvilz but not boxed format the site is full width that is just the photo shop borders

Comment: that you phanther for editing my content and making it runnable.

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap your navbar in a `.container` div. Then target it and set a max-width of your choice. E.G. `960px`

```css
.custom-container {
border:1px solid red;
max-width:760px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Start of container for navbar -->
<div class="container custom-container">
<!-- Start of container for navbar -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>

<!-- End of container for navbar -->
</div>
<!-- End of container for navbar -->
```

Comment: You may need to also add a `margin:0 auto;` to center the `.container`

Comment: its not the width its the padding left and right of the menu bar ur missing the point.

Comment: You wouldn't need to touch padding if you reduce the width... I assume you're wanting to affect the padding to change the width of the entire menu to make it tighter, no? Your explanation isn't very clear. Either way, if you want it to look like the picture then reducing the navbars overall width like I suggested will definitely do the trick.

Comment: Its making the whole site narrow all I want is to make the navbar and content area 960 so that it confirms to the psd

Comment: @David Thats because you're wrapping the entire site in the container div.... just wrap the navbar in it alone. See the comments in my edited answer. I've highlighted where it should start and where it should end.